# How Can I work with Leaflet Control Geocode?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, geocoder

I plan to add a `leaflet` control geocoder or a search box to my app.
Although I wrote the needed code it doesn't display any geocoder and
I don't know what is wrong. I have provided a part of my `index.html`
file including related code.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'geocoder/Control.Geocoder.css' %}" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'geocoder/Control.Geocoder.js' %}"></script>

<script>
var geocoder = L.Control.geocoder().on('markgeocode', function(event) {
     var center = event.geocode.center;
     L.marker(center).addTo(map);
     map.setView(center, map.getZoom());
}).addTo(map);
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure the library is loading? 404 or other errors in the console?

Comment: I am using two files including Control.Geocoder.css and Control.Geocoder.js. Other parts of my map work without any problem but I don't know why It doesn't show geocoder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the geocode "type": [Types](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder#leaflet-control-geocoder--)

```
var _geocoderType = L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim();
var geocoder = L.Control.geocoder({
   geocoder: _geocoderType
}).addTo(map);

geocoder.on('markgeocode', function(event) {
     var center = event.geocode.center;
     L.marker(center).addTo(map);
     map.setView(center, map.getZoom());
});
```

Comment: Thanks... I place that part  in beginning of Map function and It is OK now